# Feasibility of using Bootstrap to merge scrolled section images into header to emulate tabs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone tell me it this design is a match for Bootstrap? I'm new to Bootstrap (and HTML 5 for that matter) but i'm looking for a framework for this project and thing Bootstrap looks interesting.

I'd like to create a single page responsive design with touches of an old style "tabbed" metaphor.
Where the old style had tabs:

```
    _____   _____   _____   _____
___/__A__\_/  B  \_/__C__\_/__D__\___
```

The new single page design would instead have a full width image of a tab for each section header:

```
 __________________________________
|    _____      My Page Header     |
|___/  A  \________________________|
    section
         content...
            _____
___________/  B  \__________________
       section
              content...
                    _____
___________________/  C  \__________
etc.
```

The responsive part is that as one scrolls down the page through the various sections, these tabs would "stack up" into the page header.  So, once you've scrolled part way down the page you would see this:

```
 ____________________________________
|    _____   _____   My Page Header  |
|___/__A__\_/  B  \__________________|


... the final bit
    of B content.

                    _____
___________________/  C  \___________
    section C
          content...
```

Where the B section image has smoothly overlaid the A section image at the bottom of the page header, and the C section image is in view.

Combined images could easily be used if overlaying images is not feasible. 
I've been looking though Bootstrap themes looking for examples of this.  Several sync a navbar with the currently visible section header(like one called "SCROLL&STRAP - Modern Parallax One-Pager").
So is this:

1. A really stupid design.
2. Simple - this is exactly what Bootstrap is good for.  A great example is___
3. Certainly possible, but either it'll hurt or it's gonna cost you.
4. Much easier to implement if you used___instead of Bootstrap.
5. Well, maybe in CSS 5 / Bootstrap 4 but not this year.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are the tabs found in the [javascript section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). And you might could make use of [jQuery's accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) as well.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I doesn't look like normal JavaScript tabs will merge into a single row as you scroll.  The accordion doesn't seem to "merge" sections either. I'd like to have all the sections "below" the current scroll point to be expanded.